# Tag excerpts don't support formatting, but their revision history seems to suggest so

Tags: bug, markdown, revisions-list, tag-wiki-excerpt

Tag excerpts don't support formatting ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-lucene/info)). However, their [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7743566/revisions) seems to suggest so:

[image]

Comment: I get that it's a dupe, but the linked post is *8 years old* with no official response. Was this not worth bringing back up again?

Comment: @zcoop98 Posting a duplicate isn't a good way to get staff attention for old bug reports. See [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](/a/306398) for better ways.